# Reactjs - Assigning json response to default array

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, cockpit

I'm using `react-image-gallery` for displaying gallery. I need to load images from json response. My code follows,

```
let imagesArray = [
 {
    original: 'images/products/4.jpg'
 },
 {
    original: 'images/products/2.jpg'
 },
 {
    original: 'images/products/3.jpg'
 }
];

export default class Products extends React.Component {
  loadGallery () {
    var requestUrl = 'http://myurl';
    var myInit = { method: 'GET',
               mode: 'cors',
               cache: 'default' };
    fetch(requestUrl).then(response =>
      response.json().then(data => ({
          data: data,
          status: response.status
      })
    ).then(res => {
        let imagesArray = imagesArray.map((img,i)=>{ return {original: res.data[i].path.split(':')[1]}})
    }));
  }
   render() {
    return (
      <div className="products-page" onLoad={ this.loadGallery() }>
        <ImageGallery
          ref={i => this._imageGallery = i}
          items={imagesArray}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I got an error of **`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`**

if I use `let newArray = imagesArray.map((img,i)=>{ return {original: res.data[i].path.split(':')[1]}})` it will assign the value to `newArray`

Here how can I assign the json response to `imagesArray`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what I understand is correct you want to load a set of images and pass the data as array to `ImageGallery` component.

There is also something wrong/undesired with your code:

When you do this,

```
<div className="products-page" onLoad={this.loadGallery()}>
```

You will actually invoke the function `loadGallery()` on each render, instead you should only pass the function prototype.

```
<div className="products-page" onLoad={this.loadGallery}>
```

Below you will see another approach to implement your requirement. Here we will load the images and update `Product` component's state with new `imagesArray` from JSON response. So when the state updates, component re-renders and will pass the new data to `ImageGallery` component.

```
const dummyImagesArray = [
  {
    original: 'images/products/4.jpg'
  },
  {
    original: 'images/products/2.jpg'
  },
  {
    original: 'images/products/3.jpg'
  }
];

export default class Products extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      imagesArray: dummyImagesArray
    }
  }

  loadGallery () {
    var requestUrl = 'http://myurl';
    var myInit = { method: 'GET',
               mode: 'cors',
               cache: 'default' };
    fetch(requestUrl).then(response =>
      response.json().then(data => ({
          data: data,
          status: response.status
      })
    ).then(res => {
        const imagesArray = this.state.imagesArray.map((img,i) => { return { original: res.data[i].path.split(':')[1] }; });
        this.setState({ imagesArray });
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="products-page" onLoad={this.loadGallery}>
        <ImageGallery
          ref={i => this._imageGallery = i}
          items={this.state.imagesArray}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So JSON does not actually exist in React. What you will likely need to do here is set up a class that represents the JSON data and returns it to the map. What map is basically doing is peeling back the layers of your object one by one. So something like,

```
class ImagesArray extends React.Component() {
    render() {
        return {
            <image src={this.props.original}/>
        }
    }
}
```